# Code has error at the last function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void calculate_bill(double& pizza_price);

int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to Domino's Pizzaria!\n";
cout << "\nEnter the price of the pizza: ";
double price;
cin >> price;
calculate_bill(price);

}

void add_tax(double& pizza_price)
{
pizza_price *= 0.085;

}
void calculate_tip(double& pizza_price)
{
pizza_price *= 0.15;

}


void calculate_bill(double& pizza_price)
{
add_tax(pizza_price);
calculate_tip(pizza_price);
double price = pizza_price * add_tax * calculate_tip;

cout << "The pizza with taxes and tip, your total comes to " << "$" << fixed << setprecision(2) << price;
}
```

The output should be like this:

Welcome to Domino's Pizzaria!

Enter the price of the pizza: 12.99

The pizza with taxes and tip, your total comes to $16.21

**The problem is that every time I run the code it says I have an error at the "void calculate_bill". It also says that I have an error at setprecision in which I have no clue why. Any ideas on what I did wrong? I am still learning on how to call functions so could someone tell me if I called it correctly?**

Comment: _What_ error? Are we allowed to know what it is?

Comment: BTW it's "pizzeria", and Domino's is a trademark.

Comment: You don't include the correct header for it. See e.g. [this `std::setprecision` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to see which header you need.

Comment: Also, when posting questions about build errors in the future, please include the actual error output, in full, complete and unedited, and including any informational notes. In fact, all the compiler is writing.

Comment: Please correctly indent your code so that it's readable. It is also impossible for you to "run the code" and get this kind of an error. This kind of an error generally prevents the code from being compiled in the first place, and if it doesn't get compiled, there's nothing to run.

Comment: btw at the moment your pizzeria is quite nice to their customers. The price goes down when you add tip and taxes. Even a 10dollars pizza would be only 0.1275 dollars after including tip and taxes.

Comment: the line `double price = pizza_price * add_tax...` cannot work like this. Please grab a book and read about functions and references.

Answer (score 1):

For using the `std::setprecision` you need to `#include <iomanip>`.

Also, you are sending the `pizza price` as a reference, this means you are actually changing it value on every function call. You then, recalculate it at the last statement in `calculate_bill()`, which is wrong. Try calling all functions but then just display the price from `main()`.

And btw, you surely meant `pizza_price *= 1.085;` and `pizza_price *= 1.15` didn't you? Otherwise the price will drop extremely fast for every pizza. Which we may like but definitely not your professor..